# Git says file is both changed and doesnt exist

Tags: git

I accidentally changed a file in a branch I didn't mean to. I ran `git status` and can see it is amongst my changes:

```
Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       folder/myfile.ext
```

I then run `git checkout master -- folder/myfile.ext` to bring the original file back into my local branch. However, I then get the message:

```
error: pathspec 'folder/myfile.ext' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Of course, I've checked the path and that I am running this from the right directory, but to no avail.

Would anyone know why this is happening and what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "untracked file" means Git doesn't know about this file. It cannot check it out because it was never checked in, or it was deleted in a previous commit.

You can find out if there is an older deleted version with `git log -- folder/myfile.ext`.